# Dual Boot Mint Linux cursor freezes on F541N (aka X541NA)- how to fix?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, troubleshooting, asus

Bought [ASUS VivoBook Max- F541N](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X541NA/) with pre-installed Win 10 few days ago and dual booted into Mint Linux Sylvia (Cinnamon) 18.3 successfully

I see that the keyboard cursor (touchpad) pointer and touchpad  suddenly freezes  after a while (I don't use a mouse ). Observed on Linux Mint 18.3 and 18.2. The freeze is sure to occur the moment I initiate update ( On a few occasions the entire system is unresponsive and I need to hard reboot

- Switching to Intel Microcode (open source), rebooted and the behaviour persists (it was on *Don't change CPU microcode*)
- All updates Level 1 and 2 done (corresponding to *Keep my computer safe*)
- No difference if I update Kernel
- It’s a virgin system – nothing installed it
- Laptop tool confirms that it's running the latest BIOS
- Resource applet shows CPU usage less than 15% and memory usage less than 1.5 GB when the freeze occurs- checked multiple times

Same behavior persists over multiple installs over last few days

**tl:dr;** **How do I fix this problem?**

( It's barely a week old so I want to be very , very careful and not screw up)

Here is more information about the setup using `inxi -Fxz`

```
System:    Host: s****-X541NA Kernel: 4.13.0-45-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.6.6 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
           Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Machine:   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: X541NA v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X541NA v: 1.0
           Bios: American Megatrends v: X541NA.318 date: 02/27/2018
CPU:       Quad core Intel Pentium N4200 (-MCP-) cache: 1024 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 8755
           clock speeds: max: 2500 MHz 1: 852 MHz 2: 798 MHz 3: 842 MHz
           4: 1277 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5a84 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 505 (Broxton)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device 5a98 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:0e.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-45-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath9k bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (1.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM035 size: 1000.2GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 29G used: 6.3G (23%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: /home size: 446G used: 160M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 6.37GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda7
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 35.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 201 Uptime: 13 min Memory: 607.0/3809.0MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: If you are talking about the mouse nub. That also happens on my machine sometimes. You can restart your mouse driver to get it back with `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga Thanks but it's not just the mouse, entire system freezes, can't access anything- will edit to make it clear

Comment: After rebooting from a freeze, check the journal from a terminal with `sudo journalctl -b -1` to see if there are any errors logged shortly before the freeze. Post the errors as an edit to your question.

Comment: Are you using KDE for desktop?

Comment: @Mioriin Thanks. Right now I am trying to download and install Mint 19 (Beta) because it seems to be having better TouchPad support. If that doesn't work out, will revert to 18.x and add these inputs.

Comment: That's kind of important, so you'll have to find out what your desktop environment is. Keep in mind that I reported random freezing of KDE to their bug tracker many years ago and the bug report was never looked into, while the issue continues. So you may be experiencing the same bug. My workaround was to switch into a text console and back into DE, and that un-froze KDE UI for a few moments. Try Ctrl-Alt-F2 then Alt-F1 and see if this helps. Unless of course you are under a different desktop.

Comment: @Ajeh. No, it's not KDE, it's Cinnamon Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a workaround that may help those who visit here

Tried installing earlier versions of 18.x as also 17.x . Not all would install but those did exhibited same problem. Since the problem seemed to be with touchpad not working, decided to try Mint Linux 19 (Beta) which has better touchpad support

[Release notes of Mint Linux 19](https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tara_cinnamon.php) say

> The default touchpad driver in this edition is "libinput" (provided by the xserver-xorg-input-libinput package).
>
> If you experience problems with it, you can switch to another driver called "synaptics" (provided by the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package)

The default driver worked and this is the second day under observation

Probably the  default driver could be installed on 18.x to resolve this problem. For me, improved features in 19 are helpful so am staying on it