# Updating kernel freezes keyboard (Asus X541NA) - Dilemna

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, software-updates, asus

Background - Please see [Dual Boot Mint Linux cursor freezes on F541N (aka X541NA)- how to fix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451454/296774)

Now I am on Mint Linux 19 Cinnamon stable version and it was fine (keyboard cursor still freezes on hibernation or suspend , but that is a manageable issue for me) till yesterday, when there was a kernel update -The latest release of kernel 4.15.0-24.26-generic freezes my  keyboard cursor and keyboard also (There was gnome control center update too but I am not sure if that can cause this problem)- this I discovered on booting my system today

Using Time Shift I rolled back to previous snap shot and it is fine

Now I am confused what I should do next time when a kernel update is available

**Which is the best option and why?**

- Stick to the kernel that is fine for my laptop and ignore kernel updates forever (and face security risk)
- or should I keep updating but always choose the kernel that works fine from the Grub menu advanced options (not sure if all kernel updates will be reflected there- it is supported till 2023 so one can expect many kernel updates )
- or something else....??

Comment: I am pretty new to Linux stuff

Comment: First: forget buggy LinuxMint. Second (if the first is not an option for you): fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and pray for miracle.

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks. Just filed a bug report